# CSS - Align divs that dont share the same parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a complicated one.

I have a DIV that contains a form, and I want the title / inputs to always be aligned.

To do this, I have to align two div's that don't share the same parent and are not in the same row.

Is this possible?

Look at this codepen: https://codepen.io/dsomekh/pen/YQrWMW

```
.page{
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
    }

    .center{
        padding:0.3vw;
        background-color:white;
        justify-content:center;

    }

  .row_input{
        display:flex;
        align-items:flex-start;
        flex-direction:row;

        /*border: 5px solid skyblue;*/
    }

.row_title{
        display:flex;
        align-items:flex-end;
        flex-direction:row;

        /*border: 5px solid skyblue;*/
    }

    .row_good{
        display:flex;
        align-items:flex-start;
        flex-direction:row;

        /*border: 5px solid skyblue;*/
    }


    .inner_left{
        justify-content:baseline;
        display:flex;
        margin-right:5vw;
        min-width:10vw;
        flex-direction:column;
        flex:1;
    }

    .inner_right{
        display:flex;
        min-width:10vw;
        flex:1;
        flex-direction:column;
    }


    .title_left{
            display:flex;
            color:black;
            margin-right:5vw;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            max-width:10vw;
            min-width:10vw;

            max-width:10vw;
    align-items:flex-end;
            justify-content:flex-start;

            font-family:Calibri;
    }

    .title_right{
            display:flex;
            color:black;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            max-width:10vw;
            min-width:10vw;
            justify-content:flex-start;

            font-family:Calibri;
    }

.input_left_cb{
        display:flex;
        color:black;
        max-width:10vw;
        min-width:10vw;
        margin-right:5vw;
        flex-direction:column;
      align-items:flex-start;
    border:5x solid pink;
        font-family:Calibri;

    }



    .input_left{
        display:flex;
        color:black;
        max-width:10vw;
        min-width:10vw;
        margin-right:5vw;
        flex-direction:column;
    border:5x solid pink;
        font-family:Calibri;

    }

    .input_right{
        display:flex;
        color:black;
        max-width:10vw;
        min-width:10vw;
        flex-direction:column;

        font-family:Calibri;

    }

    .row_center{
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-bottom:0.5vw;
        justify-content:center;
    }

    .row{
        display:flex;
        margin-bottom:0.5vw;
        align-items:flex-end;
        flex-direction:row;
        margin-bottom:0.5vw;
        /*border: 5px solid skyblue;*/
    }


    .inner_left{
        justify-content:baseline;
        display:flex;
        margin-right:5vw;
        min-width:10vw;
        flex-direction:column;
        flex:1;
    }

    .inner_right{
        display:flex;
        min-width:10vw;
        flex:1;
        flex-direction:column;
    }


    .inner_center{
        display:flex;
        min-width:10vw;
        justify-content:center;
    }

    .title{
            display:flex;
            color:black;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            max-width:10vw;
            justify-content:flex-start;
            margin-right:0.5vw;

            font-family:Calibri;
    }



    .input{
        display:flex;
        color:black;
        max-width:10vw;
        flex-direction:column;
        font-family:Calibri;

    }


    .input_cb{
            display:flex;
            color:black;
            min-width:10vw;
            max-width:10vw;
            flex-direction:column;
            align-items:flex-start;
            font-family:Calibri;
    }



<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
<title>SolidCAM - recover activation</title>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
<font face="Verdana">
<p align="center"><font color=blue>In this example it looks CORRECT. As you can see the inputs / titles are always aligned.</font>
<div class="page">
    <div class="center">
            <div class="row_title">
                    <div class="title_left">Checkbox</div>
                    <div class="title_right">In this example it looks CORRECT. As you can see the inputs / titles are always aligned.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row_input">
                    <div class="input_left_cb"><input type="checkbox" name="screenshot"></div>
                    <div class="input_right"><textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></div>
            </div>
    </div> 
</div> 

<p align="center"><font color=blue>In the example below it looks IN-CORRECT. Can this be fixed without changing the html?</font>

<div class="page">
    <div class="center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="inner_left">
                    <div class="title">Checkbox</div>
                    <div class="input_CB"><input type="checkbox" name="screenshot"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="inner_right">
                    <div class="title">I want the the right title to always be aligned with left title. The input should start only only after the title has finished.</div>
                    <div class="input"><textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row_center">
                <div class="inner_center">
                    <div class="input"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
</div>
```

Thanks,
David

Comment: Can you be more specific about your requirement.

Comment: This can't be done using CSS alone and not change the markup. The reason is they can't _see_ each other and therefore won't be able to align. Well, giving them a fixed height will of course work, though that you might not want

Comment: Indeed...there is no CSS method of aligning elements that do not share a parent..not even flexbox or (AFAIK) CSS Grid. Javascript/JQ is required.

Comment: With a very small markup change, where you remove the `<div class="inner_left">`/`<div class="inner_right">` you can make it work though (in this fiddle demo I removed all classes but the once that controls the layout to make it easy to see what is going on): https://jsfiddle.net/xczqqwm5/

Comment: Let me know if this small change will be an option and I'll post that fiddle as an answer

Comment: It defiantly looks like the correct solution! I am now doing some hardcore testings. If everything turns out OK I will let you know!

Comment: Good ... posted it as an answer, so either upvote/accept or notify and I'll delete it

Comment: @LGson, your help is extremely Appreciated! Your solution has worked for me. I have approved your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done using CSS alone, without a markup change.

The reason is they can't *see* each other and therefore won't be able to align (well, giving them a fixed height will of course work, though that you might not want).

A possible workaround, which involves a small markup change where you remove the `<div class="inner_left">`/`<div class="inner_right">` elements, you can make it work though.

*In below sample I removed all classes but the one's that controls the layout to make it easy to see what is going on*

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xczqqwm5/)

Stack snippet

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.center {
  padding: 0.3vw;
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 30vw;                 /* set min width here instead of on inner elements */
}
.row_center {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 0.5vw;
  justify-content: center;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 0.5vw;
  margin-bottom: 0.5vw;
}
.row .title  {
  align-self: flex-end;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  order: 1;
}
.row .input  {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  order: 2;
}
.row .input textarea  {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="center">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="title">Checkbox</div>
        <div class="input cb">
          <input type="checkbox" name="screenshot">
        </div>

        <div class="title">I want the the right title to always be aligned with left title. The input should start only only after the title has finished.</div>
        <div class="input">
          <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row_center">
        <div class="inner_center">
          <div class="input">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could specify position of each div:

```
div.center{
top:0px;
left:20px;
}
```

and then you do the same for each divs.